# How to add data in json file?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, json-server

I tried to add data from user to my db.json file. But when I do so my component and my json server render as infinitive but the data I get from user is printed in my UI and added in my json file. Someone please tell me how I should fix this.

```
//db.json

{
  "customers": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "firstname": "Gibson",
      "lastname": "Joseph",
      "email": "Gj@xyz.com",
      "mobile": 98765
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "firstname": "Kl",
      "lastname": "Rahul",
      "email": "Klr@xyz.com",
      "mobile": 12345
    }
```

```
 function handleChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    setAddList({ ...addList, [name]: value });
  }
  function handleClick() {
    setIsPending(true);
    fetch("http://localhost:3006/customers", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      mode: "cors",
      body: JSON.stringify(addList),
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("new list addes");
      setIsPending(false);
    });
  }
```

```
import axios from "axios";
export async function getUser() {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3006/customers");
    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

```
const [userDetail, setUserDetail] = useState<Iuser[]>([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getUser().then((res: any) => {
      setUserDetail(res);
    });
  }, [userDetail]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very last code snippet you gave - why do you have [userDetail] in the dependency array of useEffect? With it - hook will be triggered every time the userDetail is changed. Which is caused by the hook itself. Remove `userDetail` from depsArray.

```
const [userDetail, setUserDetail] = useState<Iuser[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
  getUser().then((res: any) => {
    setUserDetail(res);
  });
}, [userDetail]); // <- here, just make it [] so data will be set on first render only
```

Or move the "user load and setState" code to a function inside this component so you will be able to reuse it. Inside your `handleClick` for example, in `.then` section to reload the new data if needed.